# Enable Date Period Java Script default Calender

Tags: javascript

I have a table in the database which contains some dates. I want to disable those dates in magento default calendar. The calendar is in front-end checkout process (used to add delivery date for the order). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : "date",                  // ID of the input field
    ifFormat   : "<%=systemDateFormat%>", // the date format
    button     : "triggerDate" ,          // ID of the button
    disableFunc: ??????,  
});

<style type="text/css">@import url(calendar-system.css);</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lang/calendar-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar-setup.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable dates in following way.

```
function disabledDate(date) {
            //get all dates from Server in Array
            var disabledDates = []; // add all dates with (,) separated here.
           for(i=0; i <disabledDates.length;i++)
            {
                // Parse the date one by one and match with 
            if( date.getDate() == PARSED_DATE)
            return true;                    
            }
          return false;


        };
```

And then you can add this function in your setup

```
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : "date",                  // ID of the input field
    ifFormat   : "<%=systemDateFormat%>", // the date format
    button     : "triggerDate" ,          // ID of the button
    disableFunc: disabledDate  
});
```